# Android Activity Menu

Tags: java, android, menu

I wanted to create an option menu which shows up similar to Whatsapp even if the device has its own "hardware" option button. The solution I found online worked just fine until I wanted to add another action to the Bar.

Menu:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item
            android:title=""
            android:id="@+id/addViewedMovie"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add_to_queue_black_24px"

            android:showAsAction="always"

            ></item>    
        <item
            android:title=""
            android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_more_vert_white_48dp"

            app:showAsAction="always">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/show_settings"
                    app:showAsAction="never"
                    android:title="@string/setttings"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/show_help"
                    app:showAsAction="never"
                    android:title="@string/help"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/show_about"
                    app:showAsAction="never"
                    android:title="@string/about"/>

            </menu>

        </item>

    </menu>
```

And this in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

With this the app forces the addViewedMovie Action into an Overflow-Menu. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and tell me if its work.. you should use `app:showAsAction` not `android:showAsAction` also you do not need to use submenu to show 3 dots.. just below code works fine also show 3 dots

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Movie"
        android:id="@+id/addViewedMovie"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add_to_queue_black_24px"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>  

   <item
        android:id="@+id/show_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/setttings"/>
   <item
        android:id="@+id/show_help"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
   <item
        android:id="@+id/show_about"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: @Curunir just copy paste this code and tell me its working or not?

Comment: yeah I did and it worked, otherwise I would not have checked your answer.

Comment: @Curunir so why you would not checked my answer even if it worked??

Comment: @Curunir try to express your feeling by upvote, downvote or by approving the answer. I not telling you because i want upvote but because it is an good habit to appriciate someone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
use app instead of android as app is for design support library. 
And so, in Gradle build in dependencies, you must have:  compile `com.android.support:design.....` like that. But, I have seen that you already used it below. So,

**Just use: `app:showAsAction="never"` instead of `android:showAsAction="always"` in your addViewedMovie item.**

Remember: `never` means it will be on overflow menu item. `always` means is will show in action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder name **Menu** in your **res** folder.

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:title="ABC" />
    <item android:id="@+id/abc1"
        android:title="ABC1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/abc2"
        android:title="ABC2" />
</menu>
```

In java file put this:-

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:

                return true;

            case R.id.abc:

                return true;

            case R.id.abc1:

                return true;

            case R.id.abc2;

                return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in a fragment, add below line in the onCreate

> setHasOptionsMenu(true);

And two more functions

```
     @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   }
```

Inflate your views in the above method. Listen to the action in the below one.

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```